# I have trouble understanding a VLQ flag that was disputed, given links only

Tags: discussion, support, disputed-flags

Per a comment I left:

> [*I have trouble understanding the disputed "VLQ" flag. The links here could potentially disappear one day and the rest is all but comments. Honestly, the reviewers aren't doing that good a job, if you ask me.*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59257471/why-is-this-evaluated-to-true/59257849#comment104751369_59257849).

Just as my comment reads [under this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59257849/1415724). ([image for <10K-ers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIXXN.png))

The answer contains links only and the rest are fit as a very long comment.

Why was [the flag that lead to the review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24816906) disputed?

Comment: Maybe because people saw more than *"You can find out here [Some arbitrary link](http://youranswer.deadlink)."* and didn't read the text, which actually adds no solution itself and is more conversational, and therefore just clicked "Looks ok"?

Comment: @Larnu I know and I have quite a few disputed flags that resemble the same and I didn't post about those. I have trouble understanding what constitutes a good or bad answer now and honestly, don't know where to throw myself anymore.

Comment: Personally, I would have marked it as link only, but it's the review queue is a "democracy" at the end of the day. Option with the highest votes wins.

Comment: @Larnu I wish there'd be a "link only" flag but there isn't :(  shame.

Comment: That would be nice, in truth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, that is an unfortunate outcome of that review.

The reviewers must have been taken off-guard by the fluff that surrounded those links. If you leave the links out there is nothing of value left, except the excitement and the endorsement of a "guru".

I guess you've found something that I will describe as a "high-quality link-only answer" (HQLOA). Congrats, and sorry for your disputed flag.

If the answer gets below zero we can delete vote it. The links can go as comments on an answer that is about JavaScript.

Comment: The links are about ECMAScript/JavaScript. Not sure what they add to a discussion about PHP...

Comment: Thanks Rene. This isn't the first time neither and today, well.... let's just say that it was the straw that finally broke the camel's back and had to post a question. I've read the posts about what makes for a good or bad answer and I seem to not get it for some reason. But... I'll keep on flagging as I see fit.

Comment: @HereticMonkey good call, didn't notice that

Comment: @rene I noticed there needs but one more vote to delete the answer. What will become of my question if I go and cast the last vote to delete?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner yeah, don't sweat it too much. I often go *meh* if reviewers have a different opinion.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner you can screenshot the answer and then include that in your question, stating the answer got deleted, or link to the actual review.

Comment: @rene I know, and I don't. But there comes a time where "enough is enough" and need to get to the bottom of things. I don't like nor do I want to stir some "you know what" (haha), but I do have a say in all this, accepted or not.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner been there, done that. Let me do 20 reviews in the H&I queue and I probably raise 20 mod flags for poor reviewing ...

Comment: @rene Exactly. Then I get potentially get barred for a week; yeah... real lovely. Oh well, I don't take it personally; it's the law of the land :)

Comment: My bluriness makes that mods can't focus on me, saving me from repercussions ;)

Comment: @rene Possibly a bit off-topic, but is raising mod-flags in the H&I queue something that you'd recommend others to do? The queue certainly needs some sort of 'fixing' (I actually find it wearisome and often depressing) but should we really be overloading our mods?

Comment: @Adrian-ReinstateMonica for cases where there it is at first sight clear there is nothing to fix (like one sentence questions) that have an review in triage with 100% agreement in needs editing, get flagged by me. The flags I raised got marked helpful, but it does take time as you need to hunt down the triage review to include in your mod flag. I don't think those flags needs lots of time to handle if you make clear it is a specific review action you want the mod to take a look at.

Comment: Except the mods who have special glasses that allow them to look upon rene. @Adrian Don't worry about overloading the mods. That is what we're here for. Raising flags is not a problem, unless you're raising flags for things that you could have done yourself (i.e., don't flag a post when you could fix its problems by editing). I would also recommend not raising mod flags to appeal a review ban or even question a review outcome. Use Meta for that, as happened here.